# Application not working on emulator other than 2.2 API level

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have created an application. It is working fine on Android 2.2. When I use emulator with API higher than 2.2, it's running properly, but some downloading code is not executing. It didn't store any data in SQLite. All functions works properly on Android 2.2 though. Is the mistake on my code or the emulator?

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

This is My code

```
helper=new DBHelper(this);
    try
    {

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_TAG);

    db=helper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c=db.query(DBHelper.Old_Data, new String [] {DBHelper.Old_id,DBHelper.OLD_NUM}, DBHelper.Old_id+"=?",new String [] {1+""}, null, null, null);
    if(c != null)
    {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    String strIndex = c.getString(1);
    int index = Integer.parseInt(strIndex);
    c.close();

    i=0;
    Log.d("Index , Length ",index + " , " + nl.getLength());
    for (i = index; i < nl.getLength(); i++) 
    {
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

        ContentValues val = new ContentValues();
        val.put(DBHelper.TEST, parser.getValue(e, TEST));
        val.put(DBHelper.FILE, parser.getValue(e, FILE));
        val.put(DBHelper.TEST_NO, parser.getValue(e, TEST_NO));
        val.put(DBHelper.FILE_URL, parser.getValue(e, EXAM_URL));

        db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(DBHelper.EXAM_DATA, null, val);
        db.close();
    }
    if(i != index)
    {
        db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DBHelper.OLD_NUM, i);
        db.update(DBHelper.Old_Data, values, DBHelper.Old_id+"=?", new String [] {1+""});
        db.close();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(UserProfile.this, "No Exam Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    }
    catch (NullPointerException ne) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "NPE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "E", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "its run properly but sime downloading code is not executing" ?

Comment: post your code.not getting what your are saying exactly

Comment: can you show us some relative code? what does the logcat say when run on higher API.

Comment: Please post some codes

Comment: Is there any error? If yes, then post the stack trace. Have you debugged step-by-step on emulator? What was the flow your app do? Tell us what happened and what *should* happen.

Comment: yeah it is catching E and in Catch e.getMessage() returns Null

Comment: I think you are getting `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. `The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.` This has been added in Api-11. Please avoid the background process from main thread instead use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for that.

Comment: Yes. Do all your network processing inside `AsyncTask`. And yes, you can try put those code inside `doInBackground()` and test it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your doing task something like parsing/downloading data use asynctask.Download or parse your data in AsyncTask doinbackground method

Comment: Paste your code first.and in android version4.0 and above you need to parse your data in asynctask

Comment: refer this- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: yes...put it in asyntask doInBackground()

Comment: whats happening in 2.2??